# Use Shopify/draggable with Alpine.js x-for directive

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I'm trying to make the sortable plugin from Shopify working with Alpine.js but when I drag and drop the items, it generate the error in the console

> "Alpine Error: `'ReferenceError: framework is not defined'`
> Expression: `'framework'`
> Element: `"<li x-text="framework" tabindex="0" style="" class="draggable-source--is-dragging">springs</li>`

Here's a reproducible example

https://codepen.io/cbaconnier/pen/bGgxyWE?editors=1011

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div x-data="{frameworks: ['laravel', 'rails', 'django', 'springs']}">
  
<ul> 
  <template x-for="framework in frameworks" :key="framework">
    <li x-text="framework"></li>
  </template>
</ul>
  
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.8.2/dist/alpine.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@shopify/draggable@1.0.0-beta.12/lib/sortable.js"></script>
<script>
  const sortable = new Sortable.default(document.querySelectorAll('ul'), {
      draggable: 'li'
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I know there's some homemade dragable/sortable that have been done with Alpine.js but since I'm already using it with Livewire on this project and some other, it would be nice to also make it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though I would like to keep Shopify/draggable I have resigned to use SortableJS/Sortable that seems to works quit well.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div 
    x-data="{frameworks: ['laravel', 'rails', 'django', 'springs']}"
    x-init="Sortable.create($refs.items)"
>
  
<ul x-ref="items"> 
  <template x-for="framework in frameworks" :key="framework">
    <li x-text="framework"></li>
  </template>
</ul>
  
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.8.2/dist/alpine.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Sortable/1.13.0/Sortable.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```